# How to attach a xsl file and send it through Webservices ?

Tags: android, web-services

I am Developing an application in which I have to attach a `.xsl` file and some more field is also there and send them using web-services. It is not email application.

Comment: till now I am thinking to use Base64 encoding, but i am not sure about that

Comment: Again I am confused either to use SAAJ or MTOM for sending files or what so ever as attachments..!! Can any body throw some light on my thoughts??

Comment: Base64 encode the file is one option.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/download-excel-file-from-jax-rs/) link on a example of how to download a excel file via a REST service. This will get you started. Once you have more solid problems post the code so we can answer it properly for you.

Comment: bro i have to upload not download and in that link there is not complete info

Comment: the difference between upload and download is matter of direction. Base 64 encode the file and upload it.